# upstart marks dead process as running when using post-start sleep

Tags: bash, startup, upstart

I have a process that needs some time to start and could also fail. In my code example this behaviour is simulated in the script block. Dependent processes should start when the main process is started up. Hence, I added sleep 2 in the post-start script.

```
#!upstart

post-start script
    sleep 2
end script

script
    sleep 1
    false
end script
```

This works fine: **start: Job failed to start**

The problem is when the service is started two times within this 2 seconds: The first invocation fails as expected, but the second invocation works and the upstart thinks the process is running from thereon:

```
service foo start
start: Job failed to start
service foo start
foo start/running
```

Is there a better way to do this? I could also add this delay to the dependent processes, but it's not very elegant... Also without the post-start sleep the process would always start and die in the background after a short time. This way the user gets immediate feedback if the main process dies within 1 second.